# SQL Server -- Merging time series data based upon order of values, not timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, time-series

I hope I can explain this one.

I have various time based readings for different business objects.  Each reading has a timestamp and a value.  The actual time that the data for each business object starts at is different for each object.  (i. e. the data for object 1 was first recorded in June, the data for object 2 was first recorded in August)

What I need to do is aggregate (sum, average, etc.) the values among the different objects based upon the order of the readings (first value, second value) without regard to the actual time each value was

All the data points represent one value for each month.  So there is not a matching problem between business objects.  The second value for each business object is one month later than the first value, etc. etc.  The timestamp for the values have the last day of the month, but this is meaningless to the nature of the data. The year and month are what are important.

I have been dealing with this by loading the whole set of data for each business object and through code merging the data.  But I am wondering if there is a way to do this via SOL.

Anybody got an idea?

Here is some data
Here is what the data would look like

```
object ID   Date           Value
1           2010-01-31      1.0
1           2010-03-31      2.0
1           2010-04-30      3.0
2           2011-06-30     10.0
2           2011-07-31     11.0
2           2011-08-31     12.0
```

The desired result would be

```
month    Sum     Average
1        11.0     5.5
2        11.0    11.0 (there is no second month for the first object)
3        13.0     6.5
4         3.0     3.0 (there is no fourth month for the second object)
```

Comment: Forgive the concrete between my ears, but I'm losing you on why the *order* is important if you're just aggregating them? Could you post a mini-example of the data you have, and how you ultimately want it to look after merging? Would help me at least. :)

Comment: David,  the aggregates are on a month by month basis.  The value for the first month of data for oject 1 is combined with the first month of data for object 2,  the second month with the second month, etc.

Comment: New answer posted. Hope that I understood correctly this time. BTW, I think you have an error in the results, the third line should be: 3 14.0 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Using the new sample data, here is a solution:

```
;WITH PREPARED_DATA 
     AS (SELECT *, 
                Datediff(MONTH, Min(DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY ID), DATE) 
                + 1 MONTH
         FROM   DATA_TABLE) 
SELECT MONTH, 
       Sum(VALUE) AS SUM_VALUE, 
       Avg(VALUE) AS AVG_VALUE 
FROM   PREPARED_DATA 
GROUP  BY MONTH
```

You can find a working example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d863/4).

Comment: This works, but assumes that the data is fully filled for each month. Meaning that there are missing months in any of the series. This assumes that the second returned row for each object is the second month, when the second month of data might be missing. This needs to be refined to deal with offset of the months from the start of the data for each object. I am short on space for this reply, will post another time with a sample dataset and desired results.

Comment: Added data to original question, but the formatting is a bit off.  Hope people can read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH M AS (
SELECT [Object ID]
     , MIN([Date]) as [Date]
  FROM TBL
 GROUP BY [Object ID]
)
SELECT DATEDIFF(MONTH,M.[Date], D.[Date]) + 1 AS [MONTH]
     , SUM(VALUE) AS [SUM]
     , AVG(VALUE) AS [AVERAGE]
  FROM TBL D
 INNER JOIN M
    ON D.[Object ID] = m.[Object ID]
 GROUP BY DATEDIFF(MONTH,M.[Date], D.[Date])
```

Either by query is wrong of your math for month 3 is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My math was off in mny example for month 3.   Here is what I got

```
 select sum (value), dataorder + 1 
    from  (select normaldata.value,
          ((year(NormalData.DATE) - 1900) * 12) + MONTH(normaldata.date) - mintab.Mindate AS DataOrder from NormalData, (select ObjectId,
 Min(((year(date) - 1900 )* 12) + MONTH(DATE)) as Mindate from
 NormalData group by ObjectID) as MINtab where (NormalData.ObjectID =
 mintab.ObjectID)
      ) AS OrderedData group by DataOrder
```

This works on Access and SQL Server, but not Oracle.  Got to get something going on all three.  I will try your approach to see how compatible it is.